# iOS app to open website URL

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, mobile

I am new to iOS development. I am working on a simple app that will just invoke the default browser when launched.

I have the following short code in my `ViewController.swift`.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    let url = NSURL(string: "https://www.domain.com")!
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url)
    exit(0)
}
```

I've tested and it's working but it actually took almost 5 seconds before the browser is invoked.

I wonder if there is a better place for the above code so that browser is invoked immediately. The reason why this app is required is because my user want a "space" on the App Store.

Any other suggestion is welcomed.

Comment: Attempt to close the app but since not recommended by Apple, can remove. Need to understand where should I place the openURL code so that it will invoke browser almost immediately after app launch.

Comment: Also tried moving the above code into AppDelegate.swift but am still seeing the 3-5 seconds wait before the browser opens.

Answer (score 0):

you can try these same thing using the UIwebview
if you use UIwebview then you can open the particullar url faster

second sol is put UIwebView to in whole screen.......then your browser load then hide your UIwebView

Comment: In my ViewController, I tried adding the UIWebView. Still showing blank screen before opening default browser. UIWebView didn't load if I have the openURL statement.

Comment: then u can use indicator untill the browser not open

Comment: Have tried to do a UIWebView loadHTMLString BEFORE calling UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL. Problem am facing is once I have got the openURL statement, screen turns blank/black without showing the loadHTMLString. Once I have commented openURL and re-run the app, I confirm seeing the HTML string loaded.

I hope I am clear. Or how about you share your code snippet?